# How do I add whitespaces when running ffmpeg from php shell_exec

Tags: php, ffmpeg, shell-exec

I am trying to insert text overlay, and can do this, but I cannot add spaces to the text.

```
ffmpeg -i meme.mp4 -y -vf drawtext='/Users/me/Library/Fonts/Champagne & Limousines.ttf:text='testtext': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24' -codec:a copy outputtexttest.mp4 2>&1
```

The error when I make testtext test text is:

Unable to find a suitable output format for 'text: fontcolor=white: fontsize=24' text: fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: Invalid argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add double quotes around the text, not single quotes like you have:

```
echo shell_exec("$ffmpeg -i meme.mp4 -y -vf drawtext='/Users/me/Library/Fonts/Champagne & Limousines.ttf:text=''test    + infinity spaces :)   text'': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24' -codec:a copy outputtexttest.mp4 2>&1");
```